# SQL Server: How to execute UPDATE from within recursive function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, sql-function

I have a recursive scalar function that needs to update a record in another table based on the value it is returning, however UPDATE statements are not allowed in the function.

How can I update the table from within the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> UPDATE statements are not allowed in
>   the function

That's the rule - functions are not allowed to have any data-changing side-affects.

You have to use a Stored Procedure to `UPDATE`.

Comment: There is a way around this actually using `open rowset` but probably not advisable.

Comment: ok - I'm sure there are other workarounds since this must come up often. Right now I'm considering passing a table to the function, creating a copy of that table (because it will be readonly), and inserting a record that has values for an update. Then call the function with a SP that does an update for each record in the table. Seems unnecessary... are there other options here? (I might move this to a new question)

Comment: @jcoon - yeah, it may be worthwhile posting what you are actually trying to do...

Comment: follow-up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805547/how-to-use-a-recursive-function-to-update-a-table